# Bitwise negation operator of unsigned int

Tags: c

I am not able to understand why it's output is ffff it should be 0000. Let say int take 2 byte ffff will stored in memory : `1111 1111 1111 1111` so after ~a value will become: 0000 0000 0000 0000. but out put coming ffff am I missing some general concept ?

```
  #include <stdio.h>
    void main()
    {
      unsigned int a = 0xffff;
      ~a;
      printf("%x", a);
    }
```

Output : ffff

Comment: try reassigning it to itself... only a++ and ++a are unary operations..

Comment: @AurA, that's not what unary operator means.  You also have unary `+`, `-`, and `~`, which all operate on a single argument.  Only `a++` and `++a` and `a--` and `--a` change the value of the variable they're operating on.

Answer (score 5):

you should do

```
a = ~a;
```

to assign the negated value to **a**.

or if you want to just print it, do

```
 printf("%x", ~a);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `~` operator does not change the variable in place, it returns the result of the change.  So in order to perform a bitwise negation of a variable you need to assign it to itself:

```
a = ~a;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about saving the value of the operation:

```
a = ~a;
```

You did perform the bitwise `~` operation, but you did not assign the returned value to any variable.
This operator **returns** a value, and **does not modify** variable itself.

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign the value back to the variable. You are just doing ~a. You are not assigning it back to a.

```
a = ~a;
```

will give you proper output.

Answer (score 0):

In the statement

```
~a;
```

`~` operator NOT (complement) the value of `a` and its value gets discarded (unlike the unary operator `++` and `--`), i.e, `~a` does nothing to `a` unless you assign it to `a`

```
a = ~a;
```